# How to run minecraft server from python?

Tags: python, minecraft, popen

I cant figure out how to start the server using a python command.

```
s = subprocess.Popen('"D:\MC SERVER 2k19\server.jar" -jar server.jar java', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

This code runs without error but doesn't start the server in cmd.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's got to do with how you're passing your arguments.

```
subprocess.Popen(['java', '-jar', 'server.jar'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, cwd='D:\MC SERVER 2k19')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to start a Java program using CMD process from Python **and** show the window, you can use subprocess to call open another CMD terminal and run the command.

In Windows you will need to CMD-escape spaces in the path you passing to the secondary CMD process. This is done with the carrot `^`

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ['start', 'cmd', '/k', "D:\\MC^ SERVER^ 2k19\\server.jar", 
     '-jar', 'server.jar', 'java'], 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
    shell=True
)
```

Keep in mind you will **NOT** be able to retrieve any output from the secondary CMD process from Python.

I.e. the process will return nothing.

```
proc.communicate()
# returns:
(b'', b'')
```